# How to find out the location of currently used MySQL configuration file in linux

Tags: mysql, linux

How do I know which configuration file is used by MySQL currently? Is there any command or something to find it out?

Comment: This likely belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The information you want can be found by running

```
mysql --help
```

or

```
mysqld --help --verbose
```

I tried this command on my machine:

```
mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1
```

And it printed out:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: +1 Another way is 'my_print_defaults mysqld' (to find what options will be passed to mysqld when it's started).

Comment: The Default options may work on a standard system. I was working on a highly configured system and the default location wasn't available. So I used the answer below to use "locate my.cnf" which provided me the exact location of my file.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';

Answer (score 6):

mysqld --help --verbose will find only location of default configuration file. What if you use 2 MySQL instances on the same server? It's not going to help.

Good article about figuring it out:

["How to find MySQL configuration file?"](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/)

Comment: Can you Please share new link as now this article is no longer exists :(

Comment: New link here of the original article. When I have time I will update this answer with a summary: http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/

Answer (score 6):

If you are using terminal just type the following:

```
locate my.cnf
```

Comment: I have like 40 of these files using "locate" and I still have no idea which is the right one

Comment: That's fine, presuming it exists - sometimes my.conf doesn't exist.

Comment: Sometimes people use my-server.cnf or hostname.cnf

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [report process status](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm) `ps` command:

```
ps ax | grep '[m]ysqld'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should find them by default in a folder like `/etc/my.cnf`, maybe also depends on versions. From [MySQL Configuration File](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000):

> Interestingly, the scope of this file
>   can be set according to its location.
>   The settings will be considered global
>   to all MySQL servers if stored in
>   /etc/my.cnf. It will be global to a
>   specific server if located in the
>   directory where the MySQL databases
>   are stored (/usr/local/mysql/data for
>   a binary installation, or
>   /usr/local/var for a source
>   installation). Finally, its scope
>   could be limited to a specific user if
>   located in the home directory of the
>   MySQL user (~/.my.cnf). Keep in mind
>   that even if MySQL does locate a
>   my.cnf file in /etc/my.cnf (global to
>   all MySQL servers on that machine), it
>   will continue its search for a
>   server-specific file, and then a
>   user-specific file. You can think of
>   the final configuration settings as
>   being the result of the /etc/my.cnf,
>   mysql-data-dir/my.cnf, and ~/.my.cnf
>   files.

There are a few switches to package managers to list specific files.

**RPM Sytems:**

There are switches to `rpm` command, `-q` for query, and `-c` or `--configfiles` to list config files. There is also `-l` or `--list`

The `--configfiles` one didn't quiet work for me, but `--list` did list a few `.cnf` files held by `mysql-server`

```
rpm -q --list mysql-server
```

**DEB Systems:**

Also with limited success: `dpkg --listfiles mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

you can find it by running the following command

```
mysql --help
```

it will give you the mysql installed directory and all commands for mysql.

Answer (score -1):

login to mysql with proper credential and used mysql>SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'; that will give you path of where mysql stored

Comment: This does not answer the question. The default location of the config is never the $datadir.